# Why does final 'where' statement (where binary_variable = 0) add minutes to Oracle query?

Tags: oracle

I will have a query like so:

```
select order_number, cart_value, is_Europe from (
select order_number, sum(product_values) as cart_value, max(is_EUR) as is_Europe
from products
group by order_number
) ordervalues
where is_Europe = 1
```

Note the last line.

Assume the subquery returns 30 rows, 15 of which have a '1' for is_Europe, the other having a '0'. In other words, peanuts.

BUT ... adding that last line makes the query go from 20 seconds to 3+ minutes and counting. Nest it in however many subqueries.

Now, I thought I understood SQL logic in that it runs the subquery first, and that a ... trivial where statement ... filtering 30 lines ... would take nanoseconds. But not with Oracle.

What's going on here?

20 seconds to give me the full result set, then just hide the rows with a '1' or '0' (whichever I choose) -- an impossible task, it seems.

Here is the execution plan/ Explain plan from PLSQL. Note in reality, the query is very complex, contains ranks, groups, etc ... nested subqueries ... however the final thing takes 20 seconds, final append where statement (even if brought up a new level) breaks it ...

[image: execution plan - Explain plan]

It's more complicated in reality (other than my problem, which again, should run after the subquery and is filtering 30 rows, right? In reality ... the structure is something like continent (EUR, NA, ASIA) and a function calls max(decode continent, 'EUR', 1,0) as Is_EUR group by order_id. The continents is an example, it's actually some random dimension. It's determining if an order was ever "Europed" or whatever. This is the fastest way to include 'yeses' and 'nos'. I can rewrite the query here I suppose, it's just harder to change regularly. Why won't Oracle simply listen to common sense?

Comment: You should share the actual query with actual explain plan or dummy query with dummy explain plan (representative of course). This doesn't seem to be case here.

Answer (score 7):

You are missing the point. Query optimization is a very difficult and delicate job. When faced with a complex query, the optimizer has to decide between millions and billions of possible plans and find an optimal one. All that in a very short time.

The process does not always yield the absolutely best plan. Only one that the optimizer decided that it was good enough, in the short time it had. It may be the best, it may be a very good one, it may be a lousy one.

Changing the (complex) query even by adding just one WHERE condition makes the query different. Now the optimizer has to choose between millions and billions plans where many of them are **different** than before. So, in some cases, a totally different plan and access path is decided to be optimal.

Again the chosen plan may be the absolute best, just good enough or plain lousy. So, even a minor change in a complex query may result in totally different performance. Much better or much worse. Usually the Oracle optimizer does a very good job so these drastic changes in performance after a minor change are rare cases.

But there is no way it could always find the best possible plan, not with the time restriction that always exist. If we let it go through all possible plans and had 100% accurate information (statistics, etc), it would always yield the best plan but we would then have to wait for hours, days or even years for some queries ;)

Answer (score 4):

Keep in mind SQL is declarative language, and execution order is up to optimizer. For the most times CBO does quite decent job, but for the complex queries, especially if you're joining tables with views the execution plan may be very far from the optimal . In addition , the goal of optimizer is not to generate the best possible plan for a given query, but to give a plan which is "good enough" in timely fashion.

There are many ways to tune performance in Oracle.  If you run Oracle Enterprise Edition with Tuning Pack and Diagnostic Pack then it's very likely procedures from `DBMS_SQLTUNE` will do all the job for you.

If you want to tune it yourself , there are couple things I'd recommend to start with :

0 . Ensure you have proper indexes. As a rule of thumb, if a field participates in join condition (or in filtering) it's a good candidate to build an index.
 1. You can control execution to some extent by re-formulation of the query. For instance putting subquery in  `WITH` clause will more likely cause subquery to be executed first compared to having the subquery in `FROM` directly ,

```
WITH qr AS (SELEСT ... ) 
   SELECT ... 
   FROM table_1 
   INNER JOIN qr ON ...
```

vs

```
SELECT ... 
FROM table_1 
INNER JOIN (SELEСT ... )qr  ON ...
```

2. Try "good" simple hints, like  `RULE` or `ORDERED` (if any of these 2 help , statistics is a culprit (it may be out of date, or lack of extended statistics).
3. Try different optimizer mode. `ALL_ROWS` is default  in many cases `FIRST_ROWS` gives you better results.